# Objective C Sqlite Update Query Based on ID

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, sql-update

Trying to learn Sqlite without using a wrapper and have managed most things but am really stuck on UPDATE queries

I am trying to update a sting in one column based on its _ID number which is the primary Key and is unique.

I have tried all sorts of code from all over google . This one says it has worked but when I check the column has not been updated

here is the code

```
            NSDateFormatter *formatter;
            NSString        *dateString;
            formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
            dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
            NSString *IDCODE = code.stringValue;
           NSInteger b = [IDCODE integerValue];
            sqlite3 *contactDB; //Declare a pointer to sqlite database structure
            const char *dbpath = [dbPath UTF8String]; // Convert NSString to UTF-8
            if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                //Database opened successfully
                NSString *databaseName = @"vistorlog.db";
                // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
                NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
                const char *dbPath=[databasePath UTF8String];
                if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &myDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
                    NSLog(@"database Opened");
                    const char* updateQuery="update LOG set TIMEOUT='22/03/19' where _ID=1";
                    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDB, updateQuery, -1, &stmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
                        NSLog(@"Query Executed");
                    }else{
                         NSLog(@"Query NOT Executed");
                                               }
                }
                sqlite3_close(myDB);
                }
                else {
                //Failed to open database
            }
```

It opens the DB vistorlog.db ok. There is a table called LOG and there is column called TIMEOUT which is where I want the string to be updated and there is a column called _ID which is what Im basing the query on yet it won't update

eventually I want to have the update statement use the string variable dateString as the string to update and b as the integer variable for the _ID

any ideas where Im going wrong?

Any help appreciated

Mark

EDIT

WORKING CODE TO UPDATE A QUERY

```
sqlite3 *contactDB; //Declare a pointer to sqlite database structure
            const char *dbpath = [dbPath UTF8String]; // Convert NSString to UTF-8
            if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                //Database opened successfully
                NSString *databaseName = @"vistorlog.db";
                // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
                NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
                const char *dbPath=[databasePath UTF8String];
                if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &myDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
                    NSLog(@"database Opened");

// define dateString and IDCODE as strings before this
                    const char *updateQuery = "Update log set TIMEOUT=? where _ID=?";
                    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
                    // Prepare Stment
                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDB, updateQuery, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [dateString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [IDCODE UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);                            if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE) {
                            NSLog(@"Query Executed");
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"Query NOT Executed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(myDB));
                        }
                        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

                    }else{
                        NSLog(@"Statement NOT Prepared: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(myDB));
                    }
                }
                sqlite3_close(myDB);
                }
                else {
                //Failed to open database
            }
```

Don't forget to import sqlite3.h

Mark

Comment: What type of field is TIMEOUT? Also you can print out the error message that is being generated by using `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_errmsg(myDB)]` do this after your sqlite3_prepare_v2 statement. That should at least tell you what error is happening on the update call.

Comment: Why do you call `sqlite3_open` twice? Why do you only close one of them?

Comment: all fields are text except the _ID which is an Integar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only preparing the statement but not actually executing it.

You need to execute [`sqlite3_step()`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) after you execute [`sqlite3_prepare_v2`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html)

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDB, updateQuery, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"Query Executed");       
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Query NOT Executed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(myDB));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

}else{
    NSLog(@"Statement NOT Prepared: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(myDB));
}
```

Comment: And you need to finalize the prepared statement when done with it.

Comment: Good point but not finalizing the statement doesn't keep the row from being updated, it just leads to resource leaks.

Comment: Add calls to `sqlite3_errmsg` to each `else` branch to demonstrate proper error logging.

Comment: I changed it. The point here wasn't to write perfect shippable code, the point here is conceptually this is what you need to get the data into the database.

Comment: Yeah but too many people (the OP and future readers) will simply copy & paste. Better to show a proper example to better help others. There is way too many crappy answers leading to terrible code. The better your answer, the better it helps future readers (and your reputation).

Comment: Point taken. Thanks :-)

Comment: totally agree with you rmaddy thats what I am trying to a compile a list of full examples on basic stuff for newbies like me I will try all your suggestion when I get home from Work Thanks all

Comment: Thanks all It works a Treat Have put full code in original question above. How do I now put variable in place of the strings? have tried const char* updateQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"update LOG set TIMEOUT='%@' _ID='%ld'", dateString,(long)b]; but I get error “Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'const char *' is disallowed with ARC”

Comment: Don't Worry guys figured it out thanks to stack overflow updated code above